# Updating Ubuntu/ Impact

Tags: updates, backup

Hi My wife's laptop is running Ubuntu 12.04LTS and looking to update to latest 16.04 LTS, I have created a startup USB with latest iso file + performed data backup of the account :-

1) Can the system be updated directly from laptop downloads location OR does it need to be booted from USB ( SD card drive ?) to perform the update ?

2) The backup probably only contained account data and not any existing programs - when I do the system update - does the HD get erased and ONLY a system image installed i.e I lose all other programs ?

3) Is there a way to backup existing programs and re-install once the new system is installed?

4) Any other gotchas I need to prepare for ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 4):

One note - if you wait a month, you can get 18.04

1. It's possible to boot the .iso and install from a hard drive but
   it's probably easier to use a USB.  I've only managed to do it the
   first way on systems with more than one physical drive, and I had to
   edit some grub configuration files to do it.
2. You are offered options when you do the install. 
   Here is what the options screen looks like on a preliminary version of 18.04:

[image]

Note that as @user68186 mentioned in a comment, there is an option to "upgrade" while keeping your files and your programs "where possible".  I personally haven't used this option.

3. You can use [aptik](http://www.teejeetech.in/p/aptik.html) to back up the list of your installed
   programs and reinstall them.
4. Make sure you have solid, tested backups of your data.

Comment: A few years ago the Ubuntu installer gave a choice to install while preserving data and programs if it found an older version of Ubuntu installed. I don't know if that is still the case. When I tried it, not all programs were preserved. So, backup is a must.

Comment: @user68186 thanks for that comment.  Since I always use "something else", I didn't read the other options carefully.  Updating answer.